# Looking for a way to make this JS effect apply to all text on my page, on load

Tags: javascript

I found [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dNXVx/665/) (not by me) and was trying to figure out how to alter it so that instead of the effect occurring when the text is clicked, the effect happens to all text on the page, when the page loads.  Thanks!

Here's the code from the fiddle:

```
function fx(o)
{
  var $o=$(o);
      $o.html($o.text().replace(/([\S])/g,'<span>$1</span>'));
      $o.css('position','relative');
      $('span',$o).stop().css({position:'relative',
                               opacity:0,
                               fontSize:84,
                               top:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);},
                               left:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);}

                       }).animate({opacity:1,fontSize:12,top:0,left:0},1000);

}
```

There is then a div on the page:

```
<div style="padding:200px;"><span onlick="fx(this)">click here</span></div>
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dNXVx/668/

Answer (score 0):

There's the fiddle with this working on the load:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dNXVx/667/)

How i got this working?

1 - give the span with the text an id, in this case `xplod`

2 - call `fx("#xplod")` on the `$(function() { })` which is the same as `$(document).ready()`